# Why "write-write-read" is a killer? (500ms ACK delay)

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

Why after a second write to socket, TCP-stack waits for ACK before allowing to do a read? I believe there is a way to avoid constant delay of up to 500 milliseconds, the "ACK delay". Could someone share the experience for internal implementation of sockets to understand the roots of this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm

Comment: Use `TCP_NODELAY` if you really need to bypass the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No *TCP-stack waits for ACK before allowing to do a read*; you can naturally call a read function at any time. Of course, the read can only return data after the other side has sent it, but it's not the "ACK delay" per se which can delay the sending, it's the *interacting with certain applications and configurations* on the other side - see [TCP delayed acknowledgment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment).